# SSIS (missing) Pre-Build and Post-Build

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, post-build-event

For the warehouse work under progress, we have a single solution with multiple projects in it

1. OLTP Database Project
2. Warehouse Database Project
3. SSIS ETL project

After the SSIS project is built, I want to move the binaries (XML, really) from the Bin folder to "C:\AutomatedTasks\ETL.Warehouse\" and "C:\AutomatedTasks\ETL"

I cannot find the Post-Build events to do that for the SSIS project. Where are they? If they aren't available, how do I achieve this?

Comment: What version of SSIS are you referring to?

Comment: @John Saunders: SSIS 2008 / Visual Studio 2008 SP1 / SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

When you specify pre- and post-build events via VS IDE, VS adds two MSBuild properties to the underlying project file: PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvent. I don't know much about how SSIS projects get built but you can try to manually edit the project file and add those properties along with the commands you need:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>copy "$(TargetDir)someoutput.xml" "C:\AutomatedTasks\ETL\someoutput.xml"</PostBuildEvent> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can also take a look at some of the other VS macros to see if they already capture what you need. For example, you may be able to use $(TargetPath) and $(TargetFileName) instead of hardcoding someoutput.xml if someoutput.xml is the target output.

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\AutomatedTasks\ETL\$(TargetFileName)"
```

Comment: this works with database projects, but not with SSIS projects.